# Invalid JWT using node-jsonwebtoken

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt

I'm signing a JWT as such:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
(...)
const payload = {
  exp: 604800,
  sub: user.email,
  scope: user.role
}
const token = jwt.sign(payload, config.secret)
res.json({ success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token})
```

When I copy it from my response and paste it into `jwt.io`, the signature is invalid.

What is wrong with the implementation?

[image]

Comment: Make sure your `config.secret` matches `secret` input box on jwt.io (it's "secret" by default)

Comment: Good eye. That was it. I can accept an answer if you care @SergeyLapin